# Does a "mortarboard" badge include reputation gained on bounties?

Tags: discussion, badges

If I get/exceed a gain of 200 points in a single day (by votes) I'm "capped" at 200, but I get a "mortarboard" badge in compensation.

But points from bounties and "accepted" answers do not count toward the 200 point limit.

Yet I once got a "mortarboard" badge based on a 400 bounty that was awarded (five points that day from "normal" votes).

Was that the intent of the mortarboard badge, awarded in a situation where my reputation gain was not capped?